# plugin create seo question attribute default title product

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, seo, category-attribute

I downloaded this plugin, and in default meta title product, I would select the attribute category. I do not know how to create it and how to set it. I wish in SEO product and the name and the name of the store that does not come out, I want to dump the category of product, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i nedd to help..